# Initializing Firebase Admin in App Engine standard Golang

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, go, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm on golang app engine standard. I keep getting a 403 error when I'm using a firebase. Here is the code I'm using for passing credentials for firebase. What is this api key? What am I doing wrong?

*Error:
googleapi: Error 403: The request is missing a valid API key., forbidden*

```
credJSON := []byte("{...json from firebase console...}")
creds, err := google.CredentialsFromJSON(ctx, credJSON, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/identitytoolkit",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
ops = append(ops, option.WithCredentials(creds))
fbApp, err := fb.NewApp(ctx, &fb.Config{ProjectID: projectID}, ops...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if you pass `nil` for config. The library figures out credentials on Google Cloud. So, here is the code:

```
fbApp, err := fb.NewApp(ctx, nil, ops...)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```